# Html List: How can I count the number elemnts retrieved in the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list that is populated from database results. If the list is empty I would like to notify users that nothing was retrieved. This will also be beneficial to me if I want to add extra stuff to list how many elements there currently are. Here is a sample list.

```
<ul id="sampleList">
   <li>Element 1</li>
   <li>Element 2</li>
   <li>Element 3</li>
   <li>Element 4</li>
</ul>
```

Based on this list how could I use jquery to get the number of elements inside my list? Any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Since you are getting the list from a database (I'm assuming via AJAX or a similar protocol), you could just count the number of items returned by the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$('#sampleList li').length
```